# Getting a DHCP client list with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, authentication, python-requests

I'm currently working on a python script that requires me to get a list of current clients on the local router's DHCP server. My first thought on how to do that was to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to get the webpage containing the list (`http://192.168.2.1/lan_dhcp.stm`) then parsing the data out and using it.

The problem is, sometimes, the router's web interface will ask me for a login, even if there's no password set and you just have to click submit. How can I send a request to login (`http://192.168.2.1/login.htm`) via Python in order to guarantee I'll be able to access the client list? Is there perhaps a better way to do this?
[image: The login screen with a look at the network]
`login.cgi`:

```
<html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" ></head><script>
                                      function reload(){                                      top.topFrame.location.href=top.topFrame.location.href;                                      document.location.href="lan_dhcp.stm";}
setTimeout("reload()", 900);
</script></html>
```

`form`part of the webpage

```
<form action="login.cgi" method="post" name="tF" onsubmit="checkfwVersion()">
    <input type="hidden" name="totalMSec" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="pws" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="arc_action" value="login">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="99%" height="100%" class="head_bold">
                    <br>
                    <font color="#0000ff">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Login</font>
                    <br>
                    <!--This is Login.stm-->
                    <table border="0" class="copy_1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="480" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="copy_1">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="69" height="41">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td height="41" class="body" colspan="2">
                                                    Before you can change any settings, you need to login with a password. If you have
                                                    not yet set a custom password,
                                                    then leave this field blank and
                                                    click "Submit."
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="69">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td width="146" class="body"><b>Password</b>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="250">
                                                    <input type="password" maxlength="12" size="16" name="pws_temp">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="69" class="body">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <font color="#6F4AFD"><b>Default = leave blank</b></font>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="69" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="69">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                    <nobr>
                                                        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:document.tF.reset();" value="Clear" style="{width=120px;height=22px;}"
                                                        class="submitBtn" onmouseover="window.status='Clear'; return true;"
                                                        onmouseout="window.status=''; return true;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" style="{width=120px;height=22px;}"
                                                        class="submitBtn">
                                                    </nobr>
                                                </td>


                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to real browser automation and [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). Aside from regular common browsers like `Firefox` or `Chrome`, you can also control the headless browsers, like [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/).

Here is the complete login code to get you started. Note that, according to the page source, the login form itself is inside an `iframe` - you would have to *switch to it's context* in order to locate elements of the form:

```
from selenium import webdriver

password = "My password"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://192.168.2.1/login.htm")

# switching to the main frame on the page    
driver.switch_to.frame("mainFrame")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("pws_temp")
password.send_keys(password)
password.submit()  # this would find the corresponding form and submit it

# or you can also submit the form this way: password.send_keys(password + "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is some client-side javascript code being executed in the browser - see how your `pws_temp` password value was converted into the `pws` encrypted value:

[image]

`requests` is not a browser and does not have a javascript engine built-in.

Comment: Hey @alecxe, sorry for the late answer. I tried to use the method you outlined like [**this**](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/98a540fa8081d7453677) but I got the following [**error**](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/f0a571356d0610f80b7e). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BernardMeurer might be multiple reasons for it. Could you please make a gist with a complete HTML of the page with the login form? Thanks!

Comment: @alexce, OK. I got all the files I could see using the F12 view on Chrome by using `wget`. They are as follows:  [**login.stm**](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/ad946401c3d955c9bfb3), [**login.htm**](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/d3bc8cccdfd1da966756), [**setup_top.htm**](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/0e9139e6b7f6f36b34aa), [**jquery.js**](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/9d40c521eb2ddba1bbe7).

Comment: @BernardMeurer thanks! When there is login form opened, please right click anywhere on the page, select View Page Source, copy the HTML you see into the gist, please.

Comment: Hmm, if there is no password set it works, but if any password is set it doesn't. This is the [page source](https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/34793f37cc7a4ec2e69b), I might as well leave it with no password. 
I'm also trying to use selenium to get the dhcp list page (using the same driver.get method), how can I print what the driver got to the terminal screen?

Comment: @BernardMeurer okay, got it, there is a frame you need to switch the context to, updated the code snippet - test it, please.

Comment: set a new password implemented it but then this happened : https://gist.github.com/Arengorn/a45a3adb2ab9631b18a2

Comment: @BernardMeurer now this is a problem with your code - the `password` variable you set to be a password is then shadowed by the `password` web element you found with selenium. Name the variables differently.

Comment: I thought there was something weird with that. Fixed it now. One last thing, how do I use selenium to get all the text on a page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99621/discussion-between-alecxe-and-bernard-meurer).